# AngularJS : directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to set variable in the directive's scope:

**HTML:**

```
<div personalize-product>
        Owned: {{ isOwned }}    
</div>
```

**Coffee:**

```
angular.module('yoApp').directive 'personalizeProduct', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, el, attrs) ->
        scope.isOwned = 'maybe'
```

however it does not work. I'm clearly missing something, but I cannot find an answer in angular docs.

EDIT: I should have mentioned - I don't want to pass isOwned to directive, I want the directive to be responsible for setting it.

Comment: I want to use it across the site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code:

HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="yoApp">
    <div personalize-product product-id="6">
    </div>

    <div personalize-product product-id="8">
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('yoApp', [])
  .directive('personalizeProduct', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.isOwned = attrs.productId;
      },
      template: '<div>{{isOwned}}</div>'
    }
  })
```

Comment: But ultimately I want to pass for example a productId to the directive and set isOwned per productId so I don't want to set it on a global scope and I think you're doing it in your example.

Comment: no global scope, this is only the scope you are giving the directive -> $rootScope = global scope

Comment: Then is sounds like you need an isolate scope directive so you can have multiple implementations of the directive

Comment: How can I make one? I'm not really an angular expert. :)

Comment: I'm working on something like that: http://plnkr.co/edit/AUEe3TRKXgsluc5dhPV0?p=preview

Comment: Can I somehow omit template property here? I want to have all the template inside the directive

Comment: the problem is that directives dont create scope - controllers do, but u wanna interact with the dom and have an isolated scope. I cant think of any other way to do it - simply - than this. UNless u wanna start message passing, but this seems overcomplicated to me

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of flaws in your code.

First you can populate the scope of your directive by using attributes:

```
<div personalize-product is-owned="isOwned">
```

Second, in your directive you need to declare the bindings (you can use different types of bindings - take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for details):

```
angular.module('yoApp').directive 'personalizeProduct', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope: { isOwned: '=' }
  controller: (scope) ->
    scope.isOwned = 'maybe'
```

**Update** (based on the comments added)

If you just want to have an isolated scope for your directive (but not passing anything from the parent scope) declare an empty object for scope:

```
scope: { }
```

Comment: The reason I structured that code is because I don't want to pass isOwned to directive itself. Instead I want the directive to be responsible for setting it.

Comment: @acid try to define an empty isolated scope (see update)

Comment: Could you provide a simple jsfiddle or something because it does not work in my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a module to hold your directive, you need to specify its dependencies, which are none (note the new Array).

```
angular.module('yoApp', []).directive 'personalizeProduct', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: ($scope) ->
        $scope.isOwned = 'maybe'
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mO9zA7fa0JCOCqTtJu89?p=preview).

See Creation vs Retrieval in [Developer Guide / Modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

Comment: I didn't include app definition but it's there. :) Also - your code is not working.

Comment: oops, plunker saved to a different state. how about now?

Comment: it works but the scope is global and as I said in one of the comments, I want to pass a productId to directive so I need isolate scope. Here is my code (not working): http://plnkr.co/edit/AUEe3TRKXgsluc5dhPV0?p=preview

Comment: you need to keep track of all of the scopes carefully. once you introduce an isolate scope, there will be an isOwned in the scopes of your transcluded elements, and one isOwned in the scopes of each of the isolates. To modify the value of the value of isOwned in the transcluded elements, you need to use the transclude function; check this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lguVkVbO53IELXKFsM96?p=preview